# Is there any way to donate through PayPal?

Tags: elementary-project

I don't have credit card nor bitcoins, but I have paypal. Can I make the payment using paypal?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can donate a monthly amount (minimum US$5) via Patreon:

https://www.patreon.com/elementary

Comment: Hi @Gabriel, I want to try elementary OS but to be able to download it I have to donate by credit card or bitcoins and I only have paypal, is there a way to download it and donate $ 5 USD with paypal?

Comment: @nashCode you can download the OS for $0, and then go to Patreon and donate $5 via Paypal.

Answer (score 3):

The way to download and pay with Paypal or just donate money to help is at the moment (November, 30, 2016):

Go to:

https://elementary.io

*If you want to download elementary OS and pay by PayPal:*

**STEP 1)** 
Download the OS typing `0` in the *"Custom"* section; afterwards press *"Purchase elementary OS"*.

**STEP 2)**
Click the *"Get Involved"* section located at the upper right position of your screen. Once there you will see different options to help elementary OS. After the *"General Funding"* section you have Paypal.

*If you don't need to download and just want to donate skip **STEP 1**.*

I hope elementary team will include Paypal in the Download area besides Card and Bitcoin as lots of users employ this payment method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Guys, in my opinion elementary OS should support paypal on **main page** also (not only on https://elementary.io/en/get-involved page).
   There are some users who do not have credit cards or do not want to pay with credit cards.
2. Another suggestion is to put **$0 button** in 'Pay What You Want' row. As you can see - there are some concerns if users can download elementary OS for free.

Btw. I am delighted to use elementary OS - fantastic job!
I am working on my own Gtk3 app for elementary.